# Create a folder in DXL - DOORS

Tags: scripting, ibm-cloud, requirements, ibm-doors

I am trying to make a script that will copy the contents of one project to another (ie folders and modules) in DXL. To do it, I have seen that there is the create function,

```
create(string name, string description)
```

which creates a folder... But from what I see, it creates it in the current directory where I run the script.

Is there any way that running the script in the **M** module, from the **C** folder of the **P** project, generates a folder with the **same name C** but inside the **new NP project**?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the DXL manual: `The name argument can be an absolute or relative name, and may include the path.`. So, you might have a loop like

```
Project P = project ('/P')
Item i
for i in P do {
   if (type i == 'Folder') {
      string nName = name i
      create ("/NP/" sName, "")
   }
   // recursively copy the content of the folder
}
```

Also, depending on your needs, you might want to have a look at `clipCopy` and `clipPaste`, which duplicates an entire hierarchy.

Comment: That's right. Thanks :-)